# CALayer not showing text in

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uilabel

I am trying to add CALayer in my view, layer is shown but text is hide.
 My code is as follow:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 25, height: 25))
        label.text = "5"
        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156899, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        let sublayer = label.layer
        sublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        sublayer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
```

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: Is the new layer to be added is supposed to set as a background?

Comment: @BhargavR no, it is not as background. I am adding text to my calayer.

Comment: Please put a screenshot what is expected and what you are getting.

Comment: @BhargavR, this is very straight forward question, just add this code to any where, you will see layer but not text

Comment: What is the sense of this `let sublayer = label.layer` and then add `sublayer` as `view's sublayer`? Why do you even want to do that kind of thing?

Comment: @PGDev, I have to add label as sublayer to another CALayer

Comment: Add the screenshot then so we can at least look at what you're trying to achieve through this and suggest you the approach.

Comment: try calling `label.layer.displayIfNeeded()`